# PowerShell RegEx Dates convert (dd MMM yy) to (yyyymmdd)

Tags: sql, regex, date, powershell

I have dates in a text file in the following format: 06/18/2012 (dd/mm/yyyy) which I want to convert to: 2012-18-06 (yyyyddmm) using Powershell.

```
(Get-Content C:\script\test.txt) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)", '$3$2$1'} | 
Set-Content C:\script\test.txt
```

The above seems to work fine. Though I am struggling with changing the following

```
12 Jan 2013 Test.docx    
01 February 2001 File.pptx    
Meeting 04 Feb 2012.xls    
09 September 2011.txt    
30 Jan 13.doc
```

**into (yyyyddmm)**

Is there a simple way of doing this in SQL Server or Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$lines = @'
12 Jan 2013 Test.docx    
01 February 2001 File.pptx    
Meeting 04 Feb 2012.xls    
09 September 2011.txt    
30 Jan 13.doc
'@ -split "`n"

$lines | % {[regex]::Replace($_, '(.*?)(\d+\s+\w+\s+[0-9]+)(.*?)', {param($match) $d = [DateTime]::Parse($match.groups[2].value).ToString("yyyyddMM"); "$($match.groups[1].value)$d$($match.groups[3].value)"})}
```

This uses the [regex]::Replace overload where you can specify a callback to process the matched text.  With that you can run the date part into DateTime.Parse and then reformat the way you want.